# Why are crankset "sizes" often defined by the amount of cassette sprockets?

Tags: crankset

For example: https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/components/road/category/crankset.html

Almost all of the listed cranksets have sizes listed as 2x11/3x10/3x9 - why does the amount of cassette sprockets matter when buying a crankset?

Is it physically impossible to pair, for example, a 3x10 crankset with an 11-speed cassette?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distance between chainrings (and possibly design of ramps and pins) is determined by chain external width, which is determined by number of speeds in the rear. Too narrow (higher number of speeds) and you will have chain rub, too wide (smaller number of speeds) and you will risk jamming the chain between chainrings.

I have been riding 2x10 crankset with 9 speed chain for years without problems, but on the other hand I have also seen the chain jamming which was took quite some time to fix on the road.

Comment: So basically you *can* mix, but due to size differences it's best not to - got it!

Comment: @Woodgnome: 8 speed and below all use the same size chain however, so 5,6,7,8 sprockets and chainrings can be freely mixed and matched.

Comment: I'm confused. You say you've ridden 2x10 with 9 speed for years without problems but then you also say you've seen the chain jam taking a long time to fix.

Comment: It was not my bike. I don't know if they had mismatched chain and crankset, but narrower chain makes this more likely to happen.